# why is wait() function not sending control to other thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing a program in which i want to control Two threads for communication between them , but after using wait() the second thread doesn't seems to be sending control to first thread and this both thread are in wait state only creating a deadlock .

I have tried various hacks to check the same , even debugging is not helping me anymore .

```
class Printer {
    private volatile boolean isEvenGlobal = true;
   synchronized  void  printOdd(int num)
    {
        System.out.println(isEvenGlobal+"inside PO");
        if(!isEvenGlobal) {
            try {
                System.out.println("isevenG is false so waiting ..");
                wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("comes after waituing in printODD");
        System.out.println(" num - ODD " + (num+1) );
        System.out.println("setting isEvenGlobal to False in PRINTODD");
        isEvenGlobal = false;
        notifyAll();
    }

  synchronized void  printEven(int num)
    {
        System.out.println("Inside PE"+ isEvenGlobal);
    if (isEvenGlobal) {
            try {

                System.out.println("isevenGLOBAL  is true so waiting inside PE..");
                wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("comes after waiting in printEVEN");
        System.out.println(" num EVEN " + (num));
        System.out.println("setting isEvenGlobal to True in PRINTEVEN ");
        isEvenGlobal = false;
        notifyAll();

    }
}
class Task3  extends Thread {


    int num = 0;
    int max =0;
    private String s;
    Printer print ;
    boolean iseven ;

    public Task3(String s , int max, boolean iseven) {
        this.s = s;
        this.iseven = iseven;
        this.max = max;
        this.print = new Printer();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Thread Name started --->" + s);
            while (num < max) {

                System.out.println(s + "--?"+iseven);
                if ( !iseven) {
                  //  System.out.println(num+ " " + getName());
                    print.printOdd(num);
                    //iseven = true;
                }
                if ( iseven) {

                  //  System.out.println(num+1+ " " + getName());
                    print.printEven(num);
                  //  iseven = false;
                }
                num+=2;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public class  ThreadPoolEx
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
       Task3 taskEven = new Task3(" EVEN TRHEAD " ,10 , true);
        Thread t = new Thread(taskEven);
        Task3 taskOdd = new Task3(" ODD THREAD " , 10, false);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(taskOdd);
       t.start();
       t2.start();
    }
}
```

On RUnning below output is shown

```
Thread Name started ---> EVEN TRHEAD 
 EVEN TRHEAD --?true
Inside PEtrue
isevenGLOBAL  is true so waiting inside PE..
Thread Name started ---> ODD THREAD 
 ODD THREAD --?false
trueinside PO
comes after waituing in printODD
 num - ODD 1
setting isEvenGlobal to False in PRINTODD
 ODD THREAD --?false
falseinside PO
isevenG is false so waiting ..
```

My Expectation is that when "setting isEvenGlobal to False in PRINTODD" , then just after that notifyALL() is called , now why " ODD THREAD --?false" is called as it was notified by ODD thread only and now EVEN THREAD Should start which is already waiting .

In my case both ODD and EVEN came to wait state and thus deadlock occured.

Comment: You have multiple `Printer` objects, `synchronized(this)` only works per instance

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little . I didn't completely got your point .thanks

Comment: Each `Task` has its own `Printer`. Changes to one printer don't affect other printers.

Comment: In that case , if I create a object if printer class in main method and pass it to both thread ,it should work . Will check and update . Thanks for your help guys

Comment: Don't think of `wait()` as "sending control." That's an up-side down way of looking at it. Think of `wait()` as a function that your code calls when it wants to _wait_ for some thing to happen. Think of `notify()` and `notifyAll()` as functions that your code calls when it wants to notify other threads that the thing _has_ happened.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments , problem was with Multiple Printer Objects as suggested. Initiallizing Printer objects in main method and passing them in Thread constructors helped in resolving the same